# LibHaru C Windows install issue

Tags: c, windows, gcc, libharu

I'm trying to install the *libHaru* C library for use in an IDE which uses a GCC compiler in Windows. In fact I do not know where to start from, since my attempts to launch the *./configure* command were uneffective (instructions here: [libharu Wiki - Installation](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation#Windows_except_cygwinMSYS) 
).

Here's the Windows Command Prompt result:

```
D:\carlo\Downloads>tar -xvzf D:\carlo\Downloads\libharu-libharu-RELEASE_2_3_0RC3-19-gd84867e.tar.gz
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/.gitignore
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/CHANGES
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/CMakeLists.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/INSTALL
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/LICENCE
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/Makefile.am
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/README
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/README_cmake
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/build.mk
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/buildconf.sh
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/cmake/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/cmake/modules/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/cmake/modules/haru.cmake
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/cmake/modules/summary.cmake
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/configure.in
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/CMakeLists.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/arc_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/arc_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/attach.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/attach.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/character_map.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/chfont_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/encoding_list.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/encoding_list.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/encryption.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/encryption.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ext_gstate_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ext_gstate_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/font_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/font_demo.cpp
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/font_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/grid_sheet.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/grid_sheet.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/grid_sheet.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/image_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/image_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/images/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/images/gray.jpg
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/images/rgb.jpg
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/jpeg_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/jpeg_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/jpfont_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/jpfont_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/line_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/line_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/link_annotation.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/link_annotation.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/make_rawimage.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/mbtext/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/mbtext/EUC_JP.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/mbtext/cp932.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/mbtext/cp936.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/mbtext/euc.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/mbtext/sjis.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/outline_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/outline_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/outline_demo_jp.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/permission.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/permission.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/png_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/png_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/README
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn0g01.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn0g02.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn0g04.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn0g08.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn0g16.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn2c08.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn2c16.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn3p01.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn3p02.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn3p04.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn3p08.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn4a08.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn4a16.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn6a08.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/basn6a16.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/pngsuite/maskimage.png
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/raw_image_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/raw_image_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/rawimage/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/rawimage/32_32_2color.dat
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/rawimage/32_32_gray.dat
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/rawimage/32_32_rgb.dat
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/slide_show_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/slide_show_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/text_annotation.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/text_annotation.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/text_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/text_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/text_demo2.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/text_demo2.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ttfont/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ttfont/PenguinAttack.ttf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ttfont_demo.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ttfont_demo.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ttfont_demo_jp.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/ttfont_demo_jp.pdf
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/type1/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/type1/COPYING
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/type1/README
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/type1/a010013l.afm
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/demo/type1/a010013l.pfb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/doc/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/doc/README
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/README.c#
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/Encryption.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/FontDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/ImageDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/JPFontDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/LineDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/OutlineDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/Permission.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/RawImageDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/SlideShowDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/demo/TextDemo.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/c#/hpdf.cs
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/ExtGStateDemo.dpr
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/LineDemo.dpr
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/README.delphi
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/hpdf.pas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/hpdf_consts.pas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/delphi/hpdf_types.pas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/freebasic/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/freebasic/README.freebasic
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/freebasic/hpdf.bi
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/freebasic/hpdf_consts.bi
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/freebasic/hpdf_types.bi
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/freebasic/hpdftest.bas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/History.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/README.python
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/__init__.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/c_func.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/arc_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/character_map.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/chfont_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/cnfont_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/encoding_list.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/encryption.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/ext_gstate_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/font_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/grid_sheet.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/image_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/jpeg_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/jpfont_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/line_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/link_annotation.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/make_rawimage.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/outline_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/outline_demo_jp.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/permission.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/png_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/raw_image_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/slide_show_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/text_annotation.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/text_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/text_demo2.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/ttfont_demo.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/ttfont_demo_cn.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/demo/ttfont_demo_jp.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/hpdf.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/hpdf_consts.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/hpdf_errorcode.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/python/hpdf_types.py
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/Makefile.msvc
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/arc_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/encryption.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/ext_gstater_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/font_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/jpfont_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/line_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/slide_show_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/text_demo2.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/demo/ttfont_demo.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/extconf.rb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/extconf.rb.all
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/extconf.rb.nopnglib
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/extconf.rb.nozlib
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/ruby/hpdf.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/README.vbnet
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/Encryption.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/FontDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/ImageDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/LineDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/OutlineDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/Permission.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/RawImageDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/SlideShowDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/demo/TextDemo.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb.net/hpdfvb.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/Form1.frm
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/MSSCCPRJ.SCC
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/Project1.vbp
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/Project1.vbw
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/README.vb
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/hpdf.bas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/hpdf_consts.bas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/if/vb6/hpdf_types.bas
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/.gitignore
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/Makefile.am
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_3dmeasure.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_annotation.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_catalog.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_conf.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_config.h.cmake
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_consts.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_destination.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_doc.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_encoder.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_encrypt.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_encryptdict.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_error.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_exdata.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_ext_gstate.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_font.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_fontdef.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_gstate.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_image.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_info.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_list.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_mmgr.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_namedict.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_objects.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_outline.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_page_label.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_pages.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_pdfa.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_streams.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_types.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_u3d.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_utils.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/include/hpdf_version.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/libharu.DevPackage.cmake
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.bcc32
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.bcc32_dll
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.cygwin
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.cygwin_dll
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.in
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.mingw
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.mingw_dll
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.msvc
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/Makefile.msvc_dll
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/create_make_files.sh
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/script/makeres.sh
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/.gitignore
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/CMakeLists.txt
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/Makefile.am
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_3dmeasure.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_annotation.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_array.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_binary.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_boolean.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_catalog.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_destination.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_dict.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_doc.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_doc_png.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encoder.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encoder_cns.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encoder_cnt.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encoder_jp.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encoder_kr.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encoder_utf.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encrypt.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_encryptdict.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_error.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_exdata.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_ext_gstate.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_font.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_font_cid.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_font_tt.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_font_type1.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_base14.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_cid.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_cns.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_cnt.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_jp.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_kr.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_tt.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_fontdef_type1.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_gstate.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_image.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_image_ccitt.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_image_png.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_info.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_list.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_mmgr.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_name.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_namedict.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_null.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_number.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_objects.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_outline.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_page_label.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_page_operator.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_pages.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_pdfa.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_real.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_streams.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_string.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_u3d.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_utils.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/hpdf_xref.c
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/src/t4.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/bcc32/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/bcc32/libhpdf.rc
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/bcc32/libhpdf.res
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/include/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/include/hpdf_config.h
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/libhpdf.rc.template
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/libhpdf.def
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/libhpdf_cdecl.def
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/libhpdf_cygwin.rc
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/libhpdf_cygwin.res
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/libhpdf_mingw.rc
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/mingw/libhpdf_mingw.res
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/msvc/
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/msvc/libhpdf.def
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/msvc/libhpdf.rc
x libharu-libharu-d84867e/win32/msvc/libhpdf.res
D:\carlo\Downloads\libharu-libharu-d84867e>./configure [--prefix=/usr/local] [--with-zlib] [--with-png]
"." is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: You've followed the installation instructions for Linux/Unix. Follow the ones for Windows.

Comment: I also tried in VSC++, but I don't know where to start from